# Make Object.values O(1) in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, hashmap

Javascript object are hash tables with O(1) amortized access:

```js
const a = { key1: 'hello', key2: 'world' }
console.log(a['key1']) // amortized O(1)
```

That's cool, but if i wanted to get a list of all values in JS, I have to do:

```js
Object.values(a) // O(n) to construct the array
```

I have a problem where I need both an O(1) access by key, and O(1) cast to an array of values (I dont care about keys in this situation).

Am I being unrealistic?

Comment: If you iterate over a datastructure with n entries, that's O(n).

Comment: @JonasWilms yeah, the iteration itself is. I don't know why I'm worrying about the cast.

Comment: Big O won't help you. Make a performance testcase, and test for absolute execution time. A viable candidate would be `Map` with it's `.values()` iterator.